# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_docs' when creating TensorFlow docs

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to follow the [contribution guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/community/contribute/documentation) for documentation. The required steps are:

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow tensorflow
cd tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/docs 
pip install tensorflow==2.0.0-alpha0 
python generate2.py --output_dir=/tmp/out
```

But the last command gives me:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "generate2.py", line 36, in
>   
>       from tensorflow_docs.api_generator import doc_controls ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_docs'

This is in line 36 of `generate2.py`:

```
from tensorflow_docs.api_generator import doc_controls
```

I haven't found a pip package containing `tensorflow_docs`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 20):

First install tensorflow_docs using this command:

`pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs`

Comment: I run code above but got
"ERROR: Package 'tensorflow-docs' requires a different Python: 3.8.18 not in '>=3.9'"

Answer (score 3):

first, you need to install git.

install git by using this command `conda install git` in anaconda prompt. then run the following command

```
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs
```

in jupyter notebook

OR

```
pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs
```

in anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I have a try and figure out how to solve the problem. Since I have multuple Python versions by checking "conda list" and "pip list", either the Jupyter or IDE installation method could not install tensorflow_docs into the correct directory.

*1.For Jupyter*

```
$ conda install git
$ !pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs
```

*2.For IDE*

```
$ conda install git
$ pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs
```

The problem is that pip has installed tensorflow_docs into the default directory of Python 3.6 with the following path: /home/user/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages. However, I use Python 3.9 in the conda environment in the most of the time.

*3.Copy tensorflow_docs into Python 3.9 site-packages*

It is applicable after putting tensorflow_docs to the designated directory of Python 3.9. So I can use tensorflow_docs after the following operations:

First.Download tensorflow_docs

https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/tree/master/tools/tensorflow_docs

Second.Save tensorflow_docs in Python 3.9 directory

```
/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_docs
```