# Module importation error on Python 3.8.3; No module named 'tensorflow_docs'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-module

I have been trying for fews days to follow this deep learning tutorial, https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression

But I can't find a way to import tensorflow_docs, I did try this

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55535518/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tensorflow-docs-when-creating-tensorflow

`pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs`

But I still get this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_docs'
```

I am running Python 3.8.3, through Pycharm.

Thank for your help.

Comment: Please ensure you are using the same python version as pip as just using 'pip' on some distros use python2.7.

Comment: I also tried using pip3

Comment: where exactly are you getting ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_docs```?  is this in code or during ```pip3 install ...```?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of informations, it is while running the program at the really beginning while importing all the modules. tensorflow_dows installation using pip3 did work successfully.

Comment: at the end of pip3 installation I get:
Created wheel for tensorflow-docs: filename=tensorflow_docs-[...]
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\[...]
Successfully built tensorflow-docs3 "

Answer (score 0):

tensorflow_docs was indeed in my computer but python was not looking at the directory,
I simply add

`import sys sys.path.append("C:/users/xxxx/appdata/local/programs/python/python38/lib/site-packages")`